# Installing ECB in emacs 24 in ubuntu

Tags: emacs, cedet, emacs-ecb, elpa

I understand [from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18149939/emacs-cedet-installation-package-assoc-is-obsolete?lq=1) that CEDET is installed in emacs 24 without additional installation, so I don't need to follow those instructions [here](http://cedet.sourceforge.net/setup.shtml), or the [CEDET part here](http://ecb.sourceforge.net/).

I am not using the emacs starter kit, [like this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8833235/install-ecb-with-emacs-starter-kit-in-emacs-24).

So, when I use elpa to install ecb, I get the following error:

```
Compiling file /home/mittenchops/.emacs.d/elpa/ecb-20131116.1319/ecb2/jn-file-tree.el at Mon Dec 30 16:13:57 2013
Entering directory `/home/mittenchops/.emacs.d/elpa/ecb-20131116.1319/ecb2/'
jn-file-tree.el:31:1:Error: Cannot open load file: jn-tree-node

Compiling file /home/mittenchops/.emacs.d/elpa/ecb-20131116.1319/ecb2/jn-tree-node.el at Mon Dec 30 16:13:57 2013
jn-tree-node.el:32:1:Error: Cannot open load file: jn-utils

Compiling file /home/mittenchops/.emacs.d/elpa/ecb-20131116.1319/ecb2/jn-tree-view.el at Mon Dec 30 16:13:57 2013
jn-tree-view.el:31:1:Error: Cannot open load file: jn-window

Compiling file /home/mittenchops/.emacs.d/elpa/ecb-20131116.1319/ecb2/jn-utils.el at Mon Dec 30 16:13:57 2013

Compiling file /home/mittenchops/.emacs.d/elpa/ecb-20131116.1319/ecb2/jn-window.el at Mon Dec 30 16:13:57 2013
jn-window.el:44:25:Error: Invalid lambda variable (parent jn-window-container)

Compiling file /home/mittenchops/.emacs.d/elpa/ecb-20131116.1319/ecb2/test.el at Mon Dec 30 16:13:57 2013
test.el:31:1:Error: Cannot open load file: jn-tree-view
```

Another answer pointed me to [this repository](https://github.com/alexott/ecb/tree/master/ecb2), which has jn-utils.  Can I just drop these files into my emacs.d/elpa/ecb-20131116.1319/ecb2/ directory to replace the existing jn-utils?

In general:

1. Why is this failing?
2. How can I fix it and install ECB as simply as possible in emacs 24?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I just installed `ecb` in under a minute.

1. From bash:

   ```
   cd ~/git && git clone https://github.com/alexott/ecb
   ```
2. In `~/.emacs`:

   ```
   (add-to-list 'load-path "~/git/ecb")
   (require 'ecb)
   ```

Done. `ecb-activate` brings up the code browser.

Comment: ECB can be also installed from MELPA repository - it points right now to my github